# EBS Volumes used by RDS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc, amazon-ebs

Currently I am going through the [Storage for Amazon RDS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Storage.html) documentation.

This document mentions that - Most of Amazon RDS uses Amazon Elastic Block Store (Amazon EBS) volumes for database and log storage;

It also mentions that - Depending on the amount of storage requested, Amazon RDS automatically stripes across multiple Amazon EBS volumes to enhance IOPS performance.

So my question is: How EBS volumes are allocated to RDS instance?

1. Whether these are the EBS volumes that are created automatically and attached to RDS instance during it's launch? (EBS volumes on which user don't have control??)
2. Or these are the EBS volumes which are attached to EC2 instance/instances within the same VPC in which I would like to launch my RDS instance?

Thx!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have no visibility into the EBS volumes used by your RDS instances. RDS is a managed service. You won't be able to see the EC2 instances or the EBS volumes or the S3 buckets used by your RDS databases.

Comment: Thanks Mark for your answer!